# Given two intersecting lines, how to find distance from one line's start to the intersection

Tags: trigonometry

I have two intersecting lines defined using a starting point and delta. Thus $(x_1,y_1)(x_1 + dx_1,y_1 + dy_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)(x_2 + dx_2,y_2 + dy_2)$. How do I find the distance from $(x_1,y_1)$ to the intersecting point?

[image]

Comment: Please use LaTeX for formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slope of line $1$ is given by $m = \frac{(y_1+dy_1) - y_1}{(x_1+dx_1)-x_1} = \frac{dy_1}{dx_1}$. Assume the line has no begining or end point, then it has a y-intercept $(0,b)$ and general form
$$ y = mx + b  \mbox{ where } b = y_1 - \frac{dy_1}{dx_1} x_1.$$

Similarly, slope of line $2$ is given by $M = \frac{(y_2+dy_2) - y_2}{(x_2+dx_2)-x_2} = \frac{dy_2}{dx_2}$. Assume the line has no begining or end point, then it has a y-intercept $(0,B)$ and general form
$$ y = Mx + B \mbox{ where } B = y_2 - \frac{dy_2}{dx_2} x_2.$$

If $m=M$, then the lines intersect everywhere or nowhere.

So assume not, then the lines intersect at a point $(x^*,y^*)$ satisfying $mx^*+b=Mx^*+B$, so
$$ x^* = \frac{B-b}{m-M} $$
implying
$$ y^* = mx^* + b .$$
Finally, the distance between two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x^*,y^*)$ is given by
$$ \sqrt{ |x_1-x^*|^2 + |y_1-y^*|^2} .$$

Comment: Thank you very much!